# In the admin panel, how to change the sidebar block template for specific category?

Tags: admin-panel, layout-update

In the admin panel I am editing a category and have set the "Custom Layout Update" to:

```
<reference name="widget.support">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>custom/widget-tradeclearance.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

`widget.support` is defined in my `catalog.xml`:

```
<default>
    <reference name="left">          
        <block type="core/template" as="widget.support" template="custom/widget-tradespecials.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

But this is not changing the template when I view the category page. How do I update the sidebar widget `widget.support` to show the other template?

Answer (score 0):

I have to give the block a name attribute:

```
<block type="core/template" name="widget.support" as="widget.support" template="custom/widget-tradespecials.phtml" />
```